# JSF - PropertyNotWritableException on form submission

Tags: java

I'm doing information form in java JSF and I have some problems...when I click submit I get this error:

> error:javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /index.xhtml @16,73 value="#{user.name}": The class 'com.java.example.User' does not have a writable property 'name'

user.java in write in new class not new JSd manegebean

```
<h:head>
    <title>registration form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="username">User Name</h:outputLabel></td>  
                <td><h:inputText id="name-id" value="#{user.name}"/></td> 

            </tr>


            <tr>

                <td><h:outputLabel for="email">your email</h:outputLabel></td>
                <td><h:inputText id="email-id" value="#{user.email}"/></td>


            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td><h:outputLabel for="password">Password</h:outputLabel></td>
                <td><h:inputSecret id="password-id" value="#{user.password}"/></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><h:outputLabel for="gender">gender</h:outputLabel></td>
                <td><h:selectOneRadio value="#{user.gender}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio> </td>


            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td><h:outputLabel for="adress">Adress</h:outputLabel></td>
                <td>  <h:inputTextarea value="#{user.addres}" cols="50" rows="5" /></td>

            </tr>




        </table>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="req.xhtml"></h:commandButton>



    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```
public class User {
String name;
String Email;
String password;
String gender;
String addres;

public void Setname(String n)
{
    this.name=n;
}

public void setEmail(String e)
{
    this.Email=e;
}
public void setPass(String p)
{
    this.password=p;
}
public void setGender(String g)
{
    this.gender=g;
}
public void setAddred(String a)
{
    this.addres=a;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getAddres() {
    return addres;
}
```

}

```
<h:head>
    <title>User datails</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2><h:outputText value="HELLO #{user.name}"/></h2>
    <h4><h:outputText value="you have secesfuly registerd,Your details are folowing"/></h4>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>  <b> EMAIL: </b></td>
            <td> <h:outputText value="#{user.email}"/><br/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td> <b> Password </b> </td>
            <td> <h:outputText value="#{user.password}"/><br/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <b> gender </b> </td>
            <td> <h:outputText value="#{user.gender}"/><br/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            td> <b> Addres </b> </td>
        <td> <h:outputText value="#{user.addres}"/><br/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Your setter is wrongly named: `Setname` should be `setName`. The error might come from the program not finding your setter via reflection. (but not entirely sure)

Comment: Besides this you should be more vigilant when writing code. Your field Email starts with a capital E, whereas all other fields are named in lower case.